# Put # in qmake variable

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I want to create a macro in qmake for using in c++. I wrote that:

```
PLUGIN_LOADER_HEADERS_S += "#include <$$1>\n"
```

Problem is that in qmake # is comment character. How can I put # in a variable for using in DEFINES?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer

```
PLUGIN_LOADER_HEADERS_S += "$$(LITERAL_HASH)include <$$1>\n"
```